# Copy from one workbook to another - paste values only

Tags: excel, vba

I have a small problem I am trying to solve copying from one workbook to another. The two lines which perform the copying works, but I want to copy the values only. As it is, it copies the data across but retains the cell format from the source workbook. You'll notice I have commented out the end of the lines when used throws up a run time error 1004 ("Unable to get the PasteSpecial property of the range class"). I have looked at similar problems with google search, but cannot find one which fits the bill for me. Am looking to solve this one so I can move on with my project.

TIA.

Here is a snippet of my code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton77_Click()
'Individual Induction forms - Trainee #1

Dim wbPrint As Workbook, TrIdx As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wbPrint = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\Drivers Induction Checklist.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
With wbPrint.Sheets("Induction Depot")
  TrIdx = 66 'Index for Trainee #1
  If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stats").Cells(TrIdx, 4) <> "" Then
    'Depot Induction Sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stats").Cells(TrIdx, 4).Copy Destination:=.Cells(3, 2) '.PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlPasteValues) 'Trainee Name (Top)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stats").Cells(TrIdx, 4).Copy Destination:=.Cells(60, 3) '.PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlPasteValues) 'Trainee Name (Bottom)
    .PrintOut
  End If
        'Next
       wbPrint.Close SaveChanges:=False
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably simplify things a bit and do on separate lines:

Cells(TrIdx, 4).Copy

Cells(3, 2).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

seems to work for me and wont copy across the formatting

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be rather than pasting, just set the values directly.

```
  If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stats").Cells(TrIdx, 4) <> "" Then
    'Depot Induction Sheet
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stats").Cells(TrIdx, 4).Copy Destination:=.Cells(3, 2) '.PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlPasteValues) 'Trainee Name (Top)
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stats").Cells(TrIdx, 4).Copy Destination:=.Cells(60, 3) '.PasteSpecial(Paste:=xlPasteValues) 'Trainee Name (Bottom)
    .PrintOut
  End If
```

Could become:

```
  If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stats").Cells(TrIdx, 4) <> "" Then
    'Depot Induction Sheet
    .Cells(3, 2) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stats").Cells(TrIdx, 4)
    .Cells(60, 3) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stats").Cells(TrIdx, 4)
    .PrintOut
  End If
```

Comment: This has pretty much done it for me. Thanks for that - as I said to JNevill (above) I needed a fresh perspective to solve this minor impasse.

Thanks very much :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of hitting the clipboard to do this, you can just set the value of the cell (your paste range) to the value of another cell (your copy range):

```
Private Sub CommandButton77_Click()
'Individual Induction forms - Trainee #1

Dim wbPrint As Workbook, TrIdx As Integer
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set wbPrint = Workbooks.Open("c:\temp\Drivers Induction Checklist.xlsx", ReadOnly:=True)
With wbPrint.Sheets("Induction Depot")
  TrIdx = 66 'Index for Trainee #1
  If ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stats").Cells(TrIdx, 4) <> "" Then
    'Depot Induction Sheet
    .Cells(3, 2).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stats").Cells(TrIdx, 4).Value 'Trainee Name (Top)
    .Cells(60, 3).Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Stats").Cells(TrIdx, 4).Value 'Trainee Name (Bottom)
    .PrintOut
  End If          
  wbPrint.Close SaveChanges:=False
End With

Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Don't forget to turn this back on :o
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! This has done the trick for me. 

It appears the simplest approach was best in my case. Obviously I couldn't see the wood for the tree and was good to see this from another angle.